# Get value from an array php

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, laravel

I have a jquery on click function where I am creating a new array with name weekdays, later I insert in that array values:

```
 var weekdays = {};
 weekdays['id'] = [id];
 weekdays['amount_of_points'] = [amount_points];
```

After I am doing

```
weekdays = JSON.stringify(weekdays);
parent.find($('.form_points')).append('<input type="hidden" value=' + weekdays + ' name="skills[]">');
```

all those values are going in a form inside a foreach in Laravel.

In the controller when I am calling $request->skills I am receiving

```
   array:2 [▼
    0 => "{"id":[41],"amount_of_points":[6]}"
    1 => "{"id":[40],"amount_of_points":[4]}"
   ]
```

How to get the value of id?

I have tried:

```
    foreach($request->skills as $skill){
        dd($skill['id']); // Illegal string offset id
        dd($skill->id); //Trying to get a property of a non object
     }
```

Comment: So you have an array of jsons represented as a string basically. You need to `json_decode` the values of the array or rethink your approach.

Comment: Try to `dd($request->skills);` that will give you a hint for sure

Comment: #Andrew I have tried before json decode but I was using it before foreach, now everything is working fine, thank you.
#lewis4u Take a look above and you will see that I have posted the result from $request->skills. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

you need to decode the json objects in side your `$skill` array to a php array then only you'll be able to access it like `$skill['id']`

```
foreach($request->skills as $skill){
  $newSkills = json_decode($skill)

  $newSkills['id']
}
```

Comment: This one worked out with modification $skill = json_decode($skill, true); thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
var weekdays = {};
var skill = [
    'id' => id,
    'amount_of_points' => amount_points
]
```

And, append every skill to your weekdays array

```
weekdays.push(skill);
```

In PHP

```
foreach($request->skills as $skill){
    $skill = json_decode($skill);
    var_dump($skill['id']);
    var_dump($skill['amount_points']);
}
```

Comment: This one is also working, I have used previous answer but this one is a better way to implement. The only issue is to change this part var weekdays = {};
var skill = [
    'id' => id,
    'amount_of_points' => amount_points
]
Should be something else instead of =>

Comment: Oh, yes, = instead => ))